# How to parse json from the specific array string to array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

JSON object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "myStatus": "[1 2 21 0 50 0 0 0],[2 1 3 1 50 0 0 0]"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

When we converting to the json object, it returning the myStatus is just string.
want to convert/parse as Array as it is..

Normally it should return in json object like below.

```
var jsonObj= JSON.parse(<abovestring>);
jsonObj.data.myStatus[0] => [1 2 21 0 50 0 0 0];
jsonObj.data.myStatus[0][0] => 1
jsonObj.data.myStatus[0][1] => 2
jsonObj.data.myStatus[0][2] => 21
```

Is it possible to split like this?

Comment: The string `myStatus` is not valid JSON (two top level objects, array is not delimited by commas). If you have control over the environment this is coming from you should properly serialize your data. If not, you'll need to modify the string to be able to parse it with standard JSON libraries

Comment: @IvanG. its coming from third party, so can't control over it.. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String#split` along with `Array#map` to do this:

```js
let str = "[1 2 21 0 50 0 0 0],[2 1 3 1 50 0 0 0]";
let arr = str
  .split(',')
  .map(item => item.slice(1, -1))
  .map(item => item.split(' '));

console.log(arr);
```

But this is very dirty approach, and is prone to bugs if the string format changes. You should instead try to fix your JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

the quotation marks around the list make `JSON.parse` treat it like a string, as it really is a string.

try either changing it to a valid array by removing the quotation marks, adding `[]` square brackets around the array, and adding `,` commas between elements , e.g.:

```
{
    "data": {
        "myStatus": [[1, 2, 21, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3, 1, 50, 0, 0, 0]]
    },
    "success": true
}
```

if u have no control over your json string and it must contain a string for `data.myStatus`, then you'd need an additional step to parse it manually. e.g

```
var string = jsonObj.data.myStatus;
string = `[${string}]`;
string = string.replace(/ +/g, ',');
jsonObj.data.myStatus = JSON.parse(string);
```